# React native init project is very large in size

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

Here is the versions I am using

[image]

The problem is the project I created using `react-native init AddisMereja` is of size **20MB**.

It does not have anything.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It has node_modules, android, ios folders and it's pretty normal

Comment: I mean the size of the application after I installed it on my mobile is 20MB.
I will upload a screen shot of the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are talking about the size of the `apk` file that is generated. If so you can try using app bundle and submit the app bundle to google play store which will handle it according to users device as the `apk` that is generated by default contains apps for different architectures but you will end up using only one of them.

This [blog post](https://blog.swmansion.com/make-your-react-native-app-3x-smaller-44c993eda2c9) by Krzysztof Magiera explains the process better.

Answer (score 0):

Your app size is descries after make a release apk Or sign apk.

Comment: It should not be that much large by default.